# Xamarin OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, opengl-es

I try use OpenGL ES 2.0 in Xamarin and C# for my app. But some errors happens every time. For example Xamarin's GLTriangle20 project draws only white triangle (fragment shader not working), I can't change a color. And it happens in emulator Android 4.4, in device 4.4 it's just not working.

Somebody trying this example or creating some app by OpenGL ES 2.0 in Xamarin C#?

P.S. OpenGL ES 1.1 works good but I need separate blending...

P.P.S. I was work in DirectX before and I haven't experience in OpenGL and sorry my English :)

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the errors that you are getting and any related code?

Comment: The problem was the version OpenTK 0.9. I changed to OpenTK-1, and it worked.